# Efficiently select the smallest magnitude element from each column of a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I am trying to find the minimum combination of absolute values from this matrix

```
mat = {{-351, -260, -148, -159,   1},
       {-197, -106,    6,   -5, 155},
       {-194, -103,    9,   -2, 158},
       {-104,  -13,   99,   88, 248},
       {  28,  119,  231,  220, 380}};
```

Basically, one element per column. However, with my current code, two elements from the same column has been selected (which isn't what I want).

```
For[i = 1, i < Length[diffList] + 1, i++,    
  setMin1 = {};    
  setMin2 = {};    
  setMin3 = {};    
  setMin4 = {};    
  setMin5 = {};    
  For[j = 1, j < Length[diffList[[i]]] + 1, j++,    
    setMin1 = Append[setMin1, Abs[diffList[[i, j, 1]]]];    
    setMin2 = Append[setMin2, Abs[diffList[[i, j, 2]]]];    
    setMin3 = Append[setMin3, Abs[diffList[[i, j, 3]]]];    
    setMin4 = Append[setMin4, Abs[diffList[[i, j, 4]]]];    
    setMin5 = Append[setMin5, Abs[diffList[[i, j, 5]]]];]]
```

This is what I have at the moment. Any help would be mucho appreciated!

**How can we efficiently select the smallest magnitude and combination of elements from each column of a matrix?**

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mathematica.SE, please consider taking the [tour] so you learn the basic rules of the site. Once you gain enough reputation by making [good questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) you will be able to vote up and down both questions and answers. [Your question has been answered](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), but its a good idea to wait 24hours for other answers before [accepting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the best one for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use `Composition` (`@*`)

```
Min @* Abs /@ Transpose[mat]
```

> {28, 13, 6, 2, 1}

To retain the signs:

```
MinimalBy[Abs] /@ Transpose[mat] // Flatten
```

> {28, -13, 6, -2, 1}

Comment: Hi Eldo, Just another question (maybe I should have been more specific before). I would like to make sure that only one element per column per row is selected to give the smallest sum. I'm facing the issue of 2 elements per row now. =x Thank you for your help!

Comment: I tried using the same command for another set of data, and for some reason, the double picking occurred again

{{-348 -194 -191 -101 -67 31}
{-293 -139 -136 -46 -12 86}
{-261 -107 -104 -14 20 118}
{-139 15 18 108 142 240}
{-151 3 6 96 130 228}
{4 158 161 251 285 383}}, with the elements {31,12,14,15,3,4} being selected.

Comment: I get `{4, 3, 6, 14, 12, 31}`, which is correct

Comment: Thats odd. I'll give another go!

Comment: Hi Eldo, 
 With the result you got {4, 3, 6, 14, 12, 31}, the code is taking the elements 3 and 6 from the same row. I'm hoping to grab the smallest combination of elements by taking one element per row and per column. So in this case, either {4, 3, 18, 14, 12, 31} or  {4, 15, 6, 14, 12, 31}. does that make sense?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes, that would make sense, but it also changes the original question completely invalidating the answers already given. I therefore suggest that you put this as a new question

Answer (score 10):

```
m = 
  {{-351, -260, -148, -159, 1}, 
   {-197, -106, 6, -5, 155}, 
   {-194, -103, 9, -2, 158}, 
   {-104, -13, 99, 88, 248}, 
   {28, 119, 231, 220, 380}};
```

Lets not forget that `Abs` is [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html), so we only have to map `Min`.

```
Min /@ Abs[Transpose[m]]
```

> `{28, 13, 6, 2, 1}`

Answer (score 5):

This

```
mat = {{-351, -260, -148, -159,   1},
       {-197, -106,    6,   -5, 155},
       {-194, -103,    9,   -2, 158},
       {-104,  -13,   99,   88, 248},
       {  28,  119,  231,  220, 380}};
Map[Min[Abs[#]] &, Transpose[mat]]
```

finds the minimum absolute value element in each column `{28, 13, 6, 2, 1}`

You can do the same thing without needing to understand `#` and `&` by

```
findminabs[v_] := Min[Abs[v]];
Map[findminabs, Transpose[mat]]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
MapThread[#2[[First[Ordering[#, 1]]]] &, 
   Transpose[{Abs[mat], mat}, {1, 3, 2}]]
```

> {28, -13, 6, -2, 1}

Answer (score 3):

Since the OP asked for efficiency, here a method that exploits the fact that `CompiledFunction`s with option `RuntimeAttributes->{Listable}` thread only to first level:

```
cMin = Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}},
  Min[x],
  CompilationTarget -> "C",
  RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
  Parallelization -> True
  ]

mat = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {1000, 1000}];
a = cMin[Transpose[Abs[mat]]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
b = Min /@ Abs[Transpose[mat]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
a == b

(* 0.007451 *)
(* 0.05298 *)
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mat =
  {{-351, -260, -148, -159, 1}, {-197, -106, 6, -5, 155}, 
   {-194, -103, 9, -2, 158}, {-104, -13, 99, 88, 248}, {28, 119, 231, 220, 380}};
```

To avoid transposition we can use `ArrayReduce` (new in 12.2)

```
ArrayReduce[Min @* Abs, mat, 1]
```

{28, 13, 6, 2, 1}

To retain the signs:

```
ArrayReduce[Splice @* MinimalBy[Abs], mat, 1]
```

{28, -13, 6, -2, 1}

`Splice` came with V 12.1